# How do I retrigger a previous 'while' loop

Tags: python, pygame

So I am currently mid way through coding snake, in an attempt at learning pygame. I am quite new to coding so apologies if I have explained this badly. I have a game loop which is active when running = True, when the snake hits a boundary, running becomes False, ending the game loop and switches to a different while loop that says game over. I will of course add more to this screen later down the line. I am just currently trying to figure out how to make it when I click r, within this second loop, running becomes true again, triggering the game loop once again to effectively restart this game. I would really appreciate any suggestions, thank you!

````
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_x = 400
display_y = 300
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_x, display_y))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ned's snake game")

x1 = display_x / 2
y1 = display_y / 2

x1_change = 0
y1_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 45

game_over_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 16)


def game_over():
    over_text = game_over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (200, 0, 0))
    display.blit(over_text, ((display_x / 2) - 54, (display_y / 2) - 16))


running = True

while running is True:
    print("thing")
    display.fill((50, 200, 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 0, 255), [x1, y1, 10, 10])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x1_change = -5
                y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x1_change = 5
                y1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y1_change = -5
                x1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y1_change = 5
                x1_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()

    x1 += x1_change
    y1 += y1_change

    if x1 <= 0 or x1 >= display_x or y1 <= 0 or y1 >= display_y:
        running = False
        end_screen = True

    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()

while end_screen is True:
    display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                running = True
                end_screen = False

    game_over()
    pygame.display.update()  ```
````

Comment: why don't try keeping the code to repeat in a function and then calling the function as required?

Comment: So remove the while loops and make them functions that I call instead?

Comment: Don't do `while running is True:`  Just do `while running:`

Comment: Yes, if it's code that you're going to be repeatedly using, make them functions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to put your entire `while running == True` block into a `def`.  Doing so will push a number of your variables out of scope.  To get around that you can move most of them inside of the `def` and use the `global` keyword to access the rest, as I've shown in the code.

I've called that def `playGame()`, and since you've put that block inside of `playGame()` you'll have to execute the statement `playGame()` to kickstart it, as you can see in the code.  When the `while` in `playGame()` goes false it then falls through to the `while end_screen == True` block which then checks for that `r` key and, if it finds it, re-runs `playGame()`.

This is a very quick and dirty fix to get you to where you want to be quickly, and I suspect that this has probably resulted in one or two bugs being created, but it's a start.  If I were to offer you a constructive criticism it would be that you do not have a proper game loop in your program.  If I get time later this evening I will add more commentary on that.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_x = 400
display_y = 300
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_x, display_y))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ned's snake game")


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 45

game_over_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 16)


def game_over():
    over_text = game_over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (200, 0, 0))
    display.blit(over_text, ((display_x / 2) - 54, (display_y / 2) - 16))


def playGame():
    global display_x, display_y, end_screen  #"globals" are variables defined outside of the def block
    
    x1 = display_x / 2    #moved these inside the def block
    y1 = display_y / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    #just moved this inside of a def block
    running = True
    while running is True:
        #print("thing")
        display.fill((50, 200, 20))
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 0, 255), [x1, y1, 10, 10])

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -5
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = 5
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -5
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 5
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()

        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change

        if x1 <= 0 or x1 >= display_x or y1 <= 0 or y1 >= display_y:
            running = False
            end_screen = True

        clock.tick(fps)
        pygame.display.update()

playGame()    #kickstart the game

while end_screen is True:
    display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                running = True
                end_screen = False
                playGame()    #restart the game

    game_over()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, really appreciated. I have now got it to end up working thanks to you. I put the game loop in a function, just like you did, however I then went on to make a separate one for the end_loop() and now everything works as intended.

Comment: Don't use `while running is True:`  Just use `while running:`.  
Explicitly comparing a `bool` to `True` or `False` is a beginner's mistake made by people who don't quite understand the concept of a `bool` data type.  The only time such comparisons make sense is if the value may or may not be a `bool` (e.g., if it may be `None`, `True`, or `False`).

Comment: I'm upvoting your comment because it is definitely good advice, but I would disagree that it's a beginner's mistake.  More like a beginner's paradigm.  It's absolutely correct, but I would agree that it is neither elegant nor Pythonic.

Comment: @IanMoote It makes little more sense than writing `while (((running is True) is True) is True) is True:` does.  It's *already* a `bool`.  No comparison is needed.

Comment: @TomKarzes  Well that's a bit of a ridiculously histrionic example.  [:D  Other than pedantry, what's the purpose of this, Tom?  I mean, look at the code:  of all the style problems you could have chosen, you're singling out literally the least important one.  His choice to use the more verbose form was informed by his past programming experiences or by his understanding of how the comparison works.  At the end of the day Python allows it, and I think that there are style recommendations we can make which are far more important and effective than that of terse boolean comparisons.  JMO.

Comment: @IanMoote Look at it this way:  Of all the problems in the code, this is arguably the most annoying (in spite of having no functional effect), and also the easiest to fix.  The mere fact that the example is so absurd demonstrates the pointlessness of comparing a `bool` to `True` or `False`, even at a depth of one.  It's also the easiest to spot.  When screening programmers, when something like this is seen, one immediately knows they're not dealing with an experienced Python programmer.  Also, you're basically saying stylistic problems are always the least important.  That's simply not true.